# Jsoup fails on certain sites

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I am trying to parse and manipulate HTML using jsoup. It is working perfectly fine for most URLs but fails on some. e.g.

This works:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://www.yahoo.com/politics/time-to-take-sanders-seriously-1342599418519606.html")
        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11 Firefox/19.0")
        .timeout(10*1000)
        .get();
```

This fails:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2016/02/160201215944.htm")
        .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.95 Safari/537.11 Firefox/19.0")
        .timeout(10*1000)
        .get();
```

Where could I be going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the error that you're getting for the second example?

Comment: @sparky no error. Nothing is returned.  thing the explanation by luksch makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page is a regular `HTML`. I don't know how to explain it, but if you change your request to a `POST` request, you'll get what you want, even though my browser (Firefox) gets the page with a `GET` request.
I've tried to add all the pther headers that are sent by the browser - `HOST`, `ACCEPT` etc., but only changing the requet to `POST` did the job.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that in the second example you get a short HTML back with nothing much in it except some JavaScript. So getting the page works fine. The problem is probably that the JavaScript does not get executed, which is outside the scope of JSoup, since Jsoup cannot execute JavaScript.

For that you would need a different approach, e.g. Selenium  Webdriver or HTMLUnit.

Comment: `Selenium Webdriver` or `HTMLUnit` looks like an overkill. The trick is to use `post()` instead of `get()`, as suggested by @TDG